# Are there tax implication on buying US stock while on a job transfer?

Tags: taxes, stocks, united-kingdom, transfer, relocation

I work for a startup company in San Francisco and  will be transferring to our London Office in April. Right now, I have vested a little over half of my allotted shares with the company, but have yet to purchase them.

As part of the negotiations, my company is giving me a Relocation Bonus as well as paying for my first two months out there.

My question is two-fold.

1. Is it wise to use my Relocation Bonus for purchasing my shares? I figured that since I already have a place to live lined up in London, the company would pay for my first two months and I could use the money that I save on rent for purchasing essentials for the flat / things that were necessary for the move.
2. If it were a wise decision to buy my shares, when would be the best time to buy them, in terms of taxes? Before I get to London or after the move? Would there be greater tax implications on capital gain in one country or the other?

I am very green when it comes to taxes and stocks, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wow, what a question.... There are so many issues you can bump into that I don't even know where to start. Get a **good** US-UK tax adviser. Usually I don't give specific suggestions, but in your case this firm might be helpful: http://britishamericantax.com/ , another one: American Tax Return LTD (in the UK, can't find their web site).

Comment: at that, suggesting to close as non-constructive. Waaaaaaaaay too broad (and yet, too localized) to answer.

Comment: I appreciate your responses. I've been trying to do as much research as I can, but I think that I have to find a professional to help me out.

Comment: Money is money. The decision to purchase the shares has nothing to do with the money's source, regular income, bonus, money from the sale of a baseball card, lottery winning. It's an interesting thing to observe how people treat $1000 very differently based on the source.

Comment: @Joe the tax question is a very tricky though, definitely requires a professional advice.

Comment: Understood, I was addressing his #1, which struck me as a bit odd.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it needs Professional Advice