# Is it possible to not pay self employment taxes on income reported in box 7 of 1099-MISC

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax

I was recommended an enrolled agent (EA) to help me file my taxes and he asked me to file an extension as he needs more time to read about my specific tax situation.

The EA did not go into details with my return yet, but he mentioned that although my 1099-MISC puts all my income in box 7, I would not have to pay any self employment taxes (FICA) on it, just the income tax

From what I have read so far, this raises a red flag as I understand that income reported only in box 3 is not subject to self employment taxes but all income reported in box 7 is subjected to both income and SE taxes

Since I have no income reported in box 3 and all of it in box 7, by not paying self employment taxes, the EA might be filing my taxes incorrectly?

The first name on the tax return is that of my wife (who had no income for 2102) if that helps.

My tax situation (if that could change the answer) is detailed here: [F1 student, as a non-resident, filing married separate tax return with US Citizen wife](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/19035/f1-student-as-a-non-resident-filing-married-separate-tax-return-with-us-citize)

Comment: Have you seen this: http://www.irs.gov/Help-&-Resources/Tools-&-FAQs/FAQs-for-Individuals/Frequently-Asked-Tax-Questions-&-Answers/Interest,-Dividends,-Other-Types-of-Income/1099-MISC,-Independent-Contractors,-and-Self-Employed/1099-MISC,-Independent-Contractors,-and-Self-Employed-3

Comment: @littleadv: I am not sure what to make of the content. Does it explicitly say "you have to pay SE taxes on all box 7 income no matter what"? That would mean my EA is incorrect.

Comment: Why don't you ask the EA? That's what you're paying him for, isn't it?

Comment: @littleadv: He says it's on taxable but everything I read points otherwise as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: ask him why, that's his job both to know and to explain to you. There may be cases where he would be right (I had one of those myself this year), I just don't think yours is one of them. But I may be wrong, and he is after all your hired professional.

Comment: You can also get a second opinion.  Take your taxes to another EA and ask them if you can do it this way.  If you have 2 independant EA's saying the same thing you are probably ok

Comment: A second EA told me that while this would certainly have not been possible for a person who was resident for tax purposes all year, I can argue saying that WHEN the payments were made to me I was non-resident for tax purposes. He did tell me I could expect IRS denying that and penalizing me so it was upto me to make the choice.

Answer (score 1):

F1 non-residents do not pay FICA tax.

Comment: Note that this only applies to work the F1 non-resident is cleared to perform by the United States Citizenship and Immigration Services (USCIS). See [this IRS page](http://www.irs.gov/Individuals/International-Taxpayers/Foreign-Student-Liability-for-Social-Security-and-Medicare-Taxes) for more information.